# How to estimate the chance of cosmic radiation reaching Earth?

Tags: astrophysics

Say some cosmic radiation like X-ray generated by some distant star is towards Earth, what is the chance that it reaches Earth successfully without being blocked or deviated or absorbed?

Comment: Do you mean reaches Earth, or reaches the top of the Earth's atmosphere? If you are talking about X-rays, they don't get through the Earth's atmosphere. And, do you specifically wish to know about X-rays? If you are interested in light at any wavelength then you will only get a general answer.

Comment: not specifically X-ray, what is the chance for any radiation not be blocked by some stuff inbetween? i.e. how hollow is the universe